# Cannot connect wireless

Tags: wireless

I have just completed installation of Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS, installed wireless drivers for my Broadcom 5752 WLAN device, and can see all the wireless connections that are nearby. However when I try to connect it fails. I have followed the troubleshooting guide without resolving the problem. 
Any ideas?

Comment: We need logs and outputs. At least from `sudo dmesg`

Comment: sudo dmesg output is too large. is there a specific section needed?

Comment: Here is more detailed instruction to do this via command-line https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Pastebinit. tl;dr: `sudo apt-get install pastebinit`,  `sudo dmesg| pastebinit`

Comment: Try sudo iwlist wlan0 scanning     in order to visualize the properties of the networks

Comment: Here is what I get using last command recommendation: rick@rick-S-7200N:~$ sudo apt-get install pastebinit, sudo dmesg| pastebinit
E: Unable to locate package pastebinit,
E: Unable to locate package dmesg
http://paste.ubuntu.com/12904497/
rick@rick-S-7200N:~$

Comment: using the sudo iwlist wlan0 command: rick@rick-S-7200N:~$ sudo iwlist wlan0 scanning
wlan0     Scan completed :
          Cell 01 - Address: C0:56:27:BB:36:57
                    Channel:2
                    Frequency:2.417 GHz (Channel 2)
                    Quality=69/70  Signal level=-41 dBm  
                    Encryption key:on
                    ESSID:"Eldridge"
                    Bit Rates:1 Mb/s; 2 Mb/s; 5.5 Mb/s; 11 Mb/s; 18 Mb/s
                              24 Mb/s; 36 Mb/s; 54 Mb/s
                    Bit Rates:6 Mb/s; 9 Mb/s; 12 Mb/s; 48 Mb/s

Answer (score 0):

I have corrected my wireless issue. It appears that after downloading the driver, my computer did not completely shut down on reboot. I started cold this morning and could not only see my wireless access points I can connect to all.